# STACK in c program. pop operation not working

Tags: c, stack

Guys what is wrong with this program. I am having problems with pop operation, it shows an extra value even after stack is empty. ??

```
void initstack (struct stack * p, int maxSize) 

void push (struct stack * p, int item) 

int pop (struct stack * p) 

void display (struct stack p) 

 struct stack

{

   int * a;

   int top;

   int maxSize;

};
```

Note:using d above structure and functions are mandatory..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct stack {
    int * a;
    int top;
    int maxSize;
};
void initstack(struct stack * p, int maxSize);
void push(struct stack * p, int item);
int pop(struct stack * p);
void display(struct stack p);
int StackIsEmpty(struct stack * p);
int StackIsFull(struct stack * p);
void printMenu();

int main()  {
    struct stack p;
    int data,ch, data1, m;
    printf("Enter the maximum size of the stack\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    initstack(&p,m);
    do {
    printMenu();    
    printf("Enter your choice\n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch(ch) {
      case 1:
        printf("Enter the element to be pushed\n");
        scanf("%d",&data);
        push(&p, data);
        break;
      case 2:
        data1 = pop(&p);
        if(data1 != -1000)
        printf("The popped element is %d\n",data1);
        break;
      case 3:
        printf("The contents of the stack are");
        display(p);
        printf("\n");
        break;
      default:
        exit(0);
    }
    } while(1);
    return 0;
}

void printMenu()
{
    printf("Choice 1 : Push\n");
    printf("Choice 2 : Pop\n");
    printf("Choice 3 : Display\n");
    printf("Any other choice : Exit\n");
}

void initstack(struct stack * p, int maxSize) {
    int *newContents;
  newContents=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*maxSize);
  p->a=newContents;
  p->maxSize=maxSize;
  p->top=-1; 
}

void push(struct stack * p, int item) {
    if(StackIsFull(p))
    {
      printf("Stack is full\n");
    }
  p->a[++p->top]=item;
}

void display(struct stack p) {
  int i;
  struct stack *b=&p;
  if(StackIsEmpty(b))
    printf(" {}");
  for(i=0;i<b->top;i++)
  {
    printf(" %d",b->a[i]);
  }
}

int pop(struct stack * p) {
    if(StackIsEmpty(p))
    {
      printf("Stack is empty\n");
      return -1000;
    }
  else
    return p->a[--p->top];
}

int StackIsEmpty(struct stack *p)
{
  return p->top == -1;          //p->top==-1;
}

int StackIsFull(struct stack *p)
{
  return p->top >= p->maxSize-1;
}
```

Comment: Please *do not* cast the result of malloc. That can hide errors.

Comment: Well, have you stepped through each line of code in the debugger?

Comment: removed malloc casting.. am getting no errors.. after stack gets empty if i try to pop i get 17 as result popped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, I fixed it.. works fine. thanks for all ur suggestions.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct stack {
    int * a;
    int top;
    int maxSize;
};
void initstack(struct stack * p, int maxSize);
void push(struct stack * p, int item);
int pop(struct stack * p);
void display(struct stack p);
int StackIsEmpty(struct stack * p);
int StackIsFull(struct stack * p);
void printMenu();

int main()  {
    struct stack p;
    int data,ch, data1, m;
    printf("Enter the maximum size of the stack\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    initstack(&p,m);
    do {
    printMenu();    
    printf("Enter your choice\n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch(ch) {
      case 1:
        printf("Enter the element to be pushed\n");
        scanf("%d",&data);
        push(&p, data);
        break;
      case 2:
        data1 = pop(&p);
        if(data1 != -1000)
        printf("The popped element is %d\n",data1);
        break;
      case 3:
        printf("The contents of the stack are");
        display(p);
        printf("\n");
        break;
      default:
        exit(0);
    }
    } while(1);
    return 0;
}

void printMenu()
{
    printf("Choice 1 : Push\n");
    printf("Choice 2 : Pop\n");
    printf("Choice 3 : Display\n");
    printf("Any other choice : Exit\n");
}

void initstack(struct stack * p, int maxSize) {
    int *newContents;
  newContents=malloc(sizeof(int)*maxSize);
  p->a=newContents;
  p->maxSize=maxSize;
  p->top=-1; 
}

void push(struct stack * p, int item) {
    if(StackIsFull(p))
    {
      printf("Stack is full\n");
    }
    else
    {
    p->a[++p->top]=item;  //FIXED LINE, ELSE BLOCK ADDED
    }
}

void display(struct stack p) {
  int i;
  struct stack *b=&p;
  if(StackIsEmpty(b))
    printf(" {}");
  for(i=0;i<=b->top;i++)   //FIXED PREVIOUSLY for(i=0;i<b->top;i++)
  {
    printf(" %d",b->a[i]);
  }
}

int pop(struct stack * p) {
    if(StackIsEmpty(p))
    {
      printf("Stack is empty\n");
      return -1000;
    }
  else
    return p->a[p->top--];     //FIXED PREVIOUSLY p->a[--p->top];
}

int StackIsEmpty(struct stack *p)
{
  return p->top < 0;          //FIXED PREVIOUSLY p->top==-1;
}

int StackIsFull(struct stack *p)
{
  return p->top >= p->maxSize-1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your push and pop operations:

```
p->a[++p->top]=item; // push
p->a[--p->top];      // pop
```

Let's assume the stack is empty and `top` is -1.  When you do a push, you increment `top` to 0 and write your element to `p->a[0]`.  When you pop that element, you first decrement `top` back to -1, and then try to access the element `p->a[-1]`.

This is a problem.  Not only are you popping the wrong element, you're accessing an element outside the range of your array and invoking undefined behavior.

You need to change the stack pointer *after* you access the element you want, like so:

```
p->a[++p->top] = item; // push
item = p->a[p->top--]; // pop
```

For array-based stacks, it's actually a little more natural for the stack to grow "downwards", like so:

```
p->top = p->maxSize = maxSize; // init

if ( p->top )            // p->top != 0 means room left on the stack
  p->a[--p->top] = item; // push

if ( p->top < p->maxSize ) // p->top < p->maxSize means elements left on stack 
  return p->a[p->top++];   // pop
```

This way, you don't run the risk of accessing an element outside the range of the array.  `p->top` will always be between 0 and maxSize - 1.

Finally, a style note:

You don't need to cast the result of `malloc`; it just adds visual clutter, and in some cases can suppress a useful diagnostic.  You can clean it up by simply writing:

```
 /**
  * Whitespace is your friend.  Use it.
  */
 newContents = malloc( sizeof *newContents * maxSize );
```

`sizeof *newContents` is the same as `sizeof (int)`; this way, if you ever decide to  change the type of the stack array, you don't have to worry about changing the `malloc` call itself.  Saves some maintenance headaches, reads a little easier.

**Edit**

Here's part of what's causing your headaches:

```
void push(struct stack * p, int item) {
    if(StackIsFull(p))
    {
      printf("Stack is full\n");
    }
    p->a[++p->top]=item; // DANGER WILL ROBINSON!
}
```

If the stack is full you print a warning, **and then you push the element anyway**.

You need an `else` branch in there

```
void push(struct stack * p, int item) 
{
  if(StackIsFull(p))
  {
    printf("Stack is full\n");
  }
  else
  {
    p->a[++p->top]=item;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your display logic is faulty. It has an off-by-one error and skips the topmost element.

Comment: please help me correct it bro... i am newbie to programming

Comment: @SubinSv Try fiddling around with the loop in the `display` function until it shows all stack entries. I assume you wrote this code yourself? Then you should be familiar with how it works.

Comment: as i told, am a newbie here. i took it from an internet source, and forked it with those mandatory functions..

Comment: @SubinSv It would help if you could do your homework on your own instead of copying something from the internet. You don't learn anything that way.

Comment: thank you bro,.. Actually am a php developer, and beginner in c. I was given this task by company as a part of training.. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
return p->a[--p->top];
```

In this part I think you should first

```
int result =  p->a[p->top];
```

then

```
p->top --;
return result;
```

I had same issue and that helped me.

Comment: now also am facing issues... still it produces a new output

Answer (score 0):

It hink the problem is related to push and pop functions. Both use preincrements, so the last item you push is not the first item you pop.

Your `push` does: first increment `top`, then store value in `a[top]`. So top is pointing to the newly pushed element.

Your `pop` does: first decrement `top`, then retrieve the value at `a[top]`. The value retrieved won't be the last pushed, but the previous-to-last. `top` keeps pointing at this very same value.

My suggestion: leave `push` as is, and change `pop` as this:

```
int pop(struct stack * p) {
    if(StackIsEmpty(p))
    {
      printf("Stack is empty\n");
      return -1000;
    }
  else
    return p->a[p->top--]; /* post-increment!! */
}
```

So, `push` will leave top pointing at the last pushed value. `pop` will retrieve this value, then decrement `top`, leaving it pointing at the next value to retrieve.

Comment: i tried this.. pushed 3 elements. 1 2 and 3.. when i pop i get 4 3 and 2

Comment: I've also fixed `display` function, to display the last element pushed.

Comment: fails for this input  3
1
1
1
2
1
3
1
4
3
2
2
2
2
3
4

Comment: @SubinSv: You're still pushing an element when the stack is full - you need an `else` branch in your `push` function.